# Node.js and Express middleware refactor

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous

I recently went about restructuring an application I am building to fit the service oriented architecture.  I really liked the way a certain tutorial structured his code, so I was trying to replecate a similiar strucutre in my app.

I want to abstract all my middleware out of app.js in my root so that basically all my app.js folder does is configure my express app.  I would like to abstract all my middleware out of app.js, and configure it in my index.js folder located in my server directory.  You can check my github repo below.

Please check the example repo, I would like to set up my code like this but am having lots of difficulty.  Every time I try and take the middleware out of app and run it by requiring into index my app breaks.

[Github Repo](https://github.com/JordanVera/survivor_league_app)

I am trying to structure my code like so.

[Example Repo](https://github.com/FrontendMasters/api-design-node/tree/step-12)

### App.js (located in root)

```
const express = require('express');
const app = require('./server/index');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const passport = require('passport');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

require('./server/config/passport')(passport);

// DB Config
const db = process.env.MongoURI;

mongoose.connect(db, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
  .then(() => {console.log('MONGODB Connected')})
  .catch(err => console.log(err))



app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Running on port ${port}`);
});
```

### index.js (located in server directory)

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const api = require('./api/api');


const indexRouter = require('./api/index/indexRouter');
const usersRouter = require('../server/api/user/userRoutes');

require('./middleware/appMiddleware')(app);


app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);


module.exports = app;
```

### appMiddleware.js (located in middleware directory which is inside server directory)

```
const createError = require('http-errors');
const express = require('express');
const expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts');
const path = require('path');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const logger = require('morgan');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require('passport');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();

module.exports = function(app) {
app.use(expressLayouts);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '../../views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(session({
  secret: 'secret',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use(flash());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.success_msg = req.flash('success_msg');
  res.locals.error_msg = req.flash('error_msg');
  res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
  next();
});

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
})
};
```

### Terminal Error

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory "/Users/jojovera/Documents/fantasyfootball/views"
    at Function.render (/Users/jojovera/Documents/fantasyfootball/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:580:17)
    at ServerResponse.render (/Users/jojovera/Documents/fantasyfootball/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1008:7)
    at ServerResponse.res.render (/Users/jojovera/Documents/fantasyfootball/node_modules/express-ejs-layouts/lib/express-layouts.js:77:18)
    at /Users/jojovera/Documents/fantasyfootball/server/middleware/appMiddleware.js:55:7
    at Layer.handle_error (/Users/jojovera/Documents/fantasyfootball/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:71:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/jojovera/Documents/fantasyfootball/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:315:13)
    at /Users/jojovera/Documents/fantasyfootball/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/Users/jojovera/Documents/fantasyfootball/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/jojovera/Documents/fantasyfootball/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at /Users/jojovera/Documents/fantasyfootball/server/middleware/appMiddleware.js:44:3
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/jojovera/Documents/fantasyfootball/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/jojovera/Documents/fantasyfootball/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /Users/jojovera/Documents/fantasyfootball/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/Users/jojovera/Documents/fantasyfootball/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/jojovera/Documents/fantasyfootball/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at /Users/jojovera/Documents/fantasyfootball/server/middleware/appMiddleware.js:39:3
```

Comment: For starters you're making two separate `app` objects (one in app.js and one in index.js).  You will need ONE `app` object that you export from one file and import into the other.  Then, it doesn't appear like you're even loading both files since neither one imports the other.

Comment: @jfriend00 What you said gave me quite a Eureka moment, which made me restructure my code.  Still, to no avail.  Check the updated code above if you can!  I am proactively working on the issue in case you dont see this!  I will updat any fixes If i find any.

Comment: `appMiddleware.js` includes middleware that **must** be inserted before any routes as well as middleware (error handlers) that **must** be inserted **AFTER** all routes. That means it can only be properly used by a server with no routes whatsoever